# Perform Button Segue to Table View Controller within Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, swift, segue, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I have a main screen that is a Tab Bar controller with 4 tabs. One of the tabs takes you to a navigation controller where you can click through 3 different Table View Controllers.

I also have a button on one of the other tabs. I would like this button to take the user to the end of one of the Navigation controllers.

I can perform the segue just fine, but when I use the button to get to the View Controller, the tabs on the bottom aren't there, it's just a table.

Is there any way I can segue to a View Controller within a Navigation controller from outside the navigation controller and still have the tab bar showing?

Here are some pictures of what I mean:

[image: Picture1]

[image: Picture 2]

See how at the bottom of this page there is the tab bar still? This is when you get there from the navigation controller

[image]

And in this picture, there is none (This is the friends page, same as picture above). I arrive at this by using a segue from a button from one of the other tabs.

[image]

Please let me know if I need to be more descriptive but I can't figure out how I can make this happen. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good question, I also want to know how to achieve this. This is needed for deep linking e.g.

Comment: The button in the other tab - what kind of segue does it use to present Friends?